# How do i display a matrix array(that i created using 1s and 0s) on the html canvas with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, html5-canvas

Ive done this before but cant remember how... i am trying to make a minecraft looking dude using the following array:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0];
```

What i want to do is color only the "1s" and display it on canvas. ive looked on google but all i can find is how to use a for loop to create the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw shapes to a canvas witha 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907209/how-to-draw-shapes-to-a-canvas-witha-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

### Dimensions

You need at least the width of the 2D array as you have only created a 1D array. Given the width the height can be calculated from the array length.

BTW your array is missing a few commas (end of first two rows)

### Abstraction

Generally I find it a lot easier to use a string rather than an array as a string is much easier to enter and manipulate.

With that we can also use different characters to represent 0 and 1 to help visualize what is being created.

As using a string adds some additional unneeded characters, white space and return (or new line return pair depending on editor) we can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to remove these characters from the string.

To keep the data organized we can define an object that contains the map, width.

To set the colors we can define an additional object that holds a color for each char we use in the map. For transparent cells we simply do not define that color, the rendering function will skip cells that it can not find a color for.

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0    // << missing comma
 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0    // << missing comma
 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0];
```

Thus becomes

```
const man = {
    width: 9,
    map:
        `___###___
         ___###___
         ___###___
         #########
         ##_###_##
         ##_###_##
         ##_###_##
         ####_####
         __##_##__
         __##_##__
         __##_##__
         __##_##__`.replace(/\s|\n|\r\n/gm,""), // remove unwanted chars
};
const colors = {  // Use CSS color strings
    "#": "Black",
};
```

### Rendering

We the data set out we can then create a basic draw function `function drawMap(ctx, map, colors, cellSize)`. It will except a canvas 2D context, the `map` and `colors` objects, and a value to define how large each cell `cellSize` is on the canvas (in pixels)

#### The canvas element [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)

The canvas that is used is referenced by its DOM `id` (Note that `id` must be unique) eg `<canvas id="canvas1" width="90" height="140"></canvas>` can be accessed in JavaScript as `canvas1`

#### The rendering API [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

To draw on the canvas we need the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) API (commonly named `ctx`). There is one for each canvas. To get the API for a canvas use [HTMLCanvasElement.getContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) and request the 2D API eg `const ctx =  canvas1.getContext("2d")`

See comments in demo for more information.

### Demo snippet

The demo adds some additional cell types and a second color set and draw the map in two canvas using the two color maps. This just to show how the defined data can be used.

```js
const man = {
    width: 9,
    cells:
        `___###___
         ___###___
         ___###___
         _===#===_
         ==_===_==
         ##_===_##
         ##_***_##
         ##**_**##
         __**_**__
         __**_**__
         __**_**__
         __MM_MM__
         _MMM_MMM_`.replace(/\s|\n|\r\n/gm,"")
};
const colors = {
    "#": "#CA4",
    "M": "#000",
    "*": "#4AC",    
    "=": "#C44", 
};
const mono = {
    "#": "#CA4",
    "M": "#CA4",
    "*": "#CA4",    
    "=": "#CA4", 
};
function drawMap(ctx, map, colors, cellSize) {
    var idx = 0;
    while (idx < map.cells.length) {         
        const col = colors[map.cells[idx]];  //get the cell char and lookup the color
        if (col) {                           // only if there is a color else leave it blank
        
            // use the idx to get the x, y pos of the cell
            const x = (idx % map.width) * cellSize;
            const y = (idx / map.width | 0) * cellSize;  // | 0 rounds down (floors) idx / map.width
            ctx.fillStyle = col;  
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);  // fill the cell 
        }
        idx += 1;
    }
}

drawMap(canvas1.getContext("2d"), man, colors, 10);
drawMap(canvas2.getContext("2d"), man, mono, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="140"></canvas> 
<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="140"></canvas>
```